# Send message to author without showing email address

Tags: forms, author, html, email

I'm trying to find a way to send via a simple form a message to an author (from frontend, everyone can message) without having the author email address visible in html.

Do you know if there is a plugin to manage that or we have to manually code a php function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of contact form plugins, which you can find by [searching the repository on wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=contact+form&sort=).

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the duplicate. I missed the Grunion description ("address never shown to sender..."). Seems the right solution. Thanks